# Getting data from a jtextfield and reversing it to display in another jtextfield

Tags: java

I am not sure if this has been answered before; I tried searching to see if it has but had no luck.

I am working on a homework assignment and have to have two JTextFields: one that takes the input and the second that displays the given input reversed. For example, if someone enters 12345 the output should be 54321 or if the enter Hello the output should be olleH.

I have tried everything I can thing of which is not too much. Any help or a point in the right direction would be nice. Here's my code:

```
//Importing the packages for the program.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray.reverse;


public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JLabel Normtxt, Revertxt;
    private JTextField NormInput, ReverOutput;
    private JButton Reverse, ClearFields;
    private string Text;

public Gui(){

    super("Reverse Your Input");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Normtxt = new JLabel("Enter a String to Reverse:");
    NormInput = new JTextField(" ",20);
    Revertxt = new JLabel("Here is Your String Reversed:");
    ReverOutput = new JTextField(" ",20);
    Reverse = new JButton("Reverse");
    ClearFields = new JButton("Clear");

    add(Normtxt);
    add(NormInput);
    add(Revertxt);
    add(ReverOutput);
    add(Reverse);
    add(ClearFields);

    NormInput.requestFocus();

    ReverseClass ReverseDigit = new ReverseClass();
    Reverse.addActionListener(ReverseDigit);

    //ClearClass Clear = new ClearClass();
    //ClearFields.addActionListener(Clear);

}
private class ReverseClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sb.reverse().toString());
        NormInput.getText();
        sb.reverse(NormInput); 
        Revertxt.setText(sb.reverse(NormInput).toString());


    }

}    
private class ClearClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        NormInput.setText("");
        Revertxt.setText("");
        NormInput.requestFocus();
    }
}
}``
```

Comment: Check this out: http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/12/5-ways-to-reverse-string-in-java-with-example.html

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that blog. I am trying to understand this stuff, it just seems I am having a hard time with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(NormInput.getText().trim());
Revertxt.setText(builder.reverse());
```

### **In your code replace class `ReverseClass` by following**

```
private class ReverseClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(NormInput.getText().trim());
        Revertxt.setText(builder.reverse().toString());
    }

}
```

It'll help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I took some programming class in earlier 2000's but never did anything with them. It seems now I am having to relearn the have to create the wheel. Any books or thing that you would suggest to help me with this? I am not looking forward to the other programming classes I have to take.